# Group as namespaces in SignalR

Tags: signalr

i want to have groups same as namesapces, for example group a.b.c and group a.b.e
is it possible in SignalR that a client will register to a.* , or a.b.*

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add the first user to groups a, ab, abc and the second user to groups a, ab, abe and so on?

Then you can just send to a and ab.

Comment: cause it is really not user friendly and not common

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do this. It's not supported.